# Why is it recommended to include methods inside the constructor ? - Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, methods, constructor

I am currently going through a book on Javascript and the author recommends to declare methods inside the constructor rather than putting them outside the constructor.
(I am not referring to "PROTOTYPE" keyword)

**Recommended method**

```
    function User(uname,password){
    this.uname=uname;
    this.password=password

    this.displayUser=function(){ // inside the constructor 
    document.write(this.uname+this.password);
};
}
```

**Alternative method**

```
function user(uname,password){
   this.uname=uname;
this.password=password;

}
function displayUser(){ // outside the constructor 
document.write(this.uname+this.password);
}
```

Can anybody explains me why author recommends method 1. Are there any benefits of declaring it in that way or is it a best practice?

Comment: Second method is very wrong.

Comment: Technically method 1 is how you'd do it. In the first code you create a method, in the second code is simply a function, which you could turn into a method if you call it with the proper context.

Comment: @thefourtheye - Why you say method 2 is very WRONG ?

Comment: Because it is not equivalent to the first code. How would you call `displayUser` in that case?

Comment: @FelixKling - Yes very true. I just tried what you said on netbeans. I created an instance and tried to call displayUser() with . (dot) operator. Method is not even loading, but it works fine with the method1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first code you have a constructor function with two properties (uname, password), and a method (displayUser). `this` refers to the instance when you create one with the `new` keyword:

```
var user = new User('Joe', 'abc123');
user.displayUser();
```

In the second code you have your constructor with two properties, but no methods. By creating `displayUser` as a normal function, and not bound to `this`, you have a disconnection between your instaces and the method, you cannot call `user.displayUser()` anymore. But in JavaScript everything is dynamic, you **can** call `displayUser` if you pass the context explicitly:

```
var user = new User('Joe', 'abc123');
displayUser.call(user); // `this` is `user`
```

Another common approach is adding the method to the prototype, and instead of being added to every new instance, it's shared among instances:

```
function User(uname,password){
  this.uname = uname;
  this.password = password;
}

User.prototype.displayUser = function() {
  ...
};
```

All those approaches are valid, but the last one is the most used, and has the best preformance over the first one. The second one is just inconvenient, most of the time.